# How to detect idle EC2 instance with no active SSM session

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to detect if my EC2 is idle and shutdown EC2 when it's idle.

**How am I using my EC2 instance?**

I am connecting to my EC2 instance by SSM session manager from my local and then I am SSH(ing) to the EC2 instance to run some jobs.

I sometimes don't run any job and do some very lightweight operations too with very little CPU usage.

**What do I want to achieve ?**

I want to shut down (not terminate) when I am not connected to my EC2 instance for long.

Is there any way to monitor the number of SSM sessions and terminate if there is no SSM session for long hours like (2 hours)?

I cannot use metrics like tracking CPU utilisation to call my instance idle because sometimes I may be connected to the instance by SSM Session and not running tasks.

Comment: Is it gonna only be you or other users as well?

Comment: More than one user can access that instance. Can we do something different if we have only one user?

Comment: In any case, you can check `/var/log/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.log`. When a session is closed for someone for remianing idle, you get `execution of $user-xxxxxxxxx is over.` You can monitor these logs. Another method could be `ps aux|grep $user`

Comment: AWS Trusted Advisor has detection for [Low Utilization Amazon EC2 Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/trusted-advisor-check-reference.html#low-utilization-amazon-ec2-instances). But its use depends on you support level.

Comment: @Marcin I guess AWS Trusted Advisor is more of a recommendation tool for a longer period of time. What I want to achieve is to monitor using cloudwatch metrics and raise cloudwatch Alarm to shutdown instance.

Comment: You need custom solution for that.

Comment: @Marcin yes I also think the same, anyways that's for help.

Comment: @Riz I like your idea. I can run a simple process to log the number of active SSM sessions from ec2 and use that metric to create alarms.

Comment: You can also use `aws ssm describe-sessions`.  Filter by `--state Active` will give you all active sessions. `--state History` will give you terminated sessions with their corresponding instance ids and session end time.